# How to get array of int as json result in mvc 4?

Tags: jquery, json, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

This is my json code.

```
public JsonResult GetCheckedPerm(int usr_groupId)
{   
    List<int> selectedradio = GrpPermBAL.GetData(usr_groupId);        
    return(selectedradio,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is my code to get data

```
public List<int> GetData(int groupId)
{
    return db.ts_grp_perm_mapping
             .Where(c => c.grp_id == groupId)
             .Select(c => c.perm_id)
             .ToList();
}
```

Here using above code I am returning array of int. But I am not able to result aray of int in json. I am getting below error cannot convert lambda expression type System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: Before you post, please read over the preview of the post carefully and ask yourself whether it's all presented as you'd want it to be if *you* were reading it, with pleasant code formatting etc. I've edited *this* post, but it would be better if you'd do it yourself.

Comment: Also, you're not returning an array of `int` - you're returning a `List<int>`. Confusion between arrays and lists has already bitten you on your previous question - it's worth being very clear about the differen between them.

Comment: (And as noted already, now would be a good idea to start following .NET naming conventions...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the [`Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json(System.Object)) method, inherited from the controller base class:

```
return Json(selectedradio, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```